# Deploy CKan Docker image using Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, ckan

I am trying to deploy the Ckan docker image that is being provided at https://github.com/keitaroinc/docker-ckan. I cloned the repo and tried to change the yaml config of docker compose file to change the image names to values as suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose. But it seems not to work. Anyone has any idea how can I deploy this using Azure Container Registry and Azure Container Instances?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not to work"?

Comment: I tried tagging the images with the format [acrname.azurecr.io]/imagename and pushed them to ACR. after that i created an aci context and used ```docker compose up```. But sometimes it says it is unable to find some volume source like solr_data or it says make sure the context is targetted with dokcer engine running.